# Laravel Carbon return me 0 results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I need to grab this month data for user in database so I write:

```
 dd($user->products->where('paid',1)->where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->toDateString())->all());
```

and I got 0 results...

When I try `Carbon::now()->subMonth()` its works good but return me last 30 days ...

How I can solve this? How to get only this month data ?

Comment: You might want to look into `->whereDate`

Answer (score 3):

`->toDateString()` is causing the query to look for a `string` value, and not a `date`. There's two ways to solve this:

```
(...)->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
// OR
(...)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->toDateString())
```

If you just use a `Carbon` variable, Laravel knows to check for `date` logic. Alternatively, if you're using a `string`, you can override the `where` logic to treat it as a `date` by using `->whereDate()`