# Update record where created_at is today - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried a solved questions from this site, but for me nothing worked.

This is the code

```
Items::where('item_id', $item->id)->where('created_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString())->update(['item_price' => $price]);

Items::where('item_id', $item->id)->where('created_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->update(['item_price' => $price]);
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: What is the error? what is the problem?

Comment: I answered something similar recently; there's an odd interaction between `->where()` for a `datetime` column and string data. Look into my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473220/laravel-carbon-return-me-0-results/50473384#50473384

Comment: @IamCavic I don't get any errors..simply doesn't update..

Comment: @TimLewis I will check that in a moment

Comment: No worries. Long story short, use `->whereDate()` if you use `->toTimeString()`, or `->where()` with a `Carbon` variable.

Comment: Yup.. That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@TimLewis answered

> use ->whereDate() if you use ->toTimeString(), or ->where() with a Carbon variable

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.6+, you can simply do something like:

```
Items::where('item_id', $item->id)->where('created_at', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->update(['item_price' => $price]);
```

or

```
Items::where('item_id', $item->id)->where('created_at', Carbon::today())->update(['item_price' => $price]);
```